# virtual assistant solution - deploy multiple environments

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a scenario, where my virtual assistant solution (C#) is ready in one environment /dev via create and publish .ps1 scripts.

- How can I target the same code with other Azure resources (for say qa
  and prod environments)?
- Do I have to maintain separate
  create/publish/ appsettings for each environments?
- Caveat could be if i run create.ps1, i would have new appsettings and cognitivemodel
  json files. So, how best i can plan my whole cycle of development and
  testing in other environments pointing to one code repo??
- How is it suggested from our end to follow as a practice and if any code/
  configuration modification need be done?

It would help if we have some doc/ steps around it.